# How to add items in select dynamically in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, hook-form

Could you please tell me How to add items in select dynamically in react ?

I am getting response from server (name , label etc).For example I just mock my response and after two second I fetch that .

In my example I have two select box or drop down .first dropdown have value “one” and “two”(which is given as options in json).

In json there is one more option `dependentField`  it mean the field is dependent on another field (value mentioned is dependent).In my example `second` field is dependent on first field.

So the value of second select or dropdown field will be `["three", "four"]` if first select box or dropdown value id `one`.

So the value of second select or dropdown field will be `["five", "six"]` if first select box or dropdown value id `two`.

So I need to `watch` the value of field as mention in `hook form`

https://react-hook-form.com/get-started

**Can we dynamically add options**

here is code

https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-benz-lxb8i

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("====");
    (async () => {
      var a = await FETCH_API();
      console.log("sssss");
      setState(a);
      console.log(a);
    })();
  }, []);


const getForm = () => {
    try {
      return state.map((i, index) => {
        switch (i.type) {
          case "text":
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <label>{i.label}</label>
                <input type="text" ref={register()} name={i.name} />
              </div>
            );

          case "select":
            if (i.watch) {
              watch(i.name, null);
            }
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <label>{i.label}</label>
                <select name={i.name} ref={register()}>
                  {i.options.map((i, idx) => {
                    return (
                      <option key={idx} value={i}>
                        {i}
                      </option>
                    );
                  })}
                  /
                </select>
              </div>
            );
          default:
            return <div>ddd</div>;
        }
      });
      return <div>ddd</div>;
    } catch (e) {}
  };
```

**I don’t wan’t want to do any harcoading like**

```
useEffect(()=>{


},[‘first’])
```

can we watch or add useeffect dynamically to watch change dynamically ?

Any update

Comment: I want to know how to attached event `dynamically` change event

Comment: Hi please see the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60265171/how-to-watch-field-in-react-dynamically-add-useeffect/60266723#60266723, if it does answer your question please upvote.

Comment: here's the code https://codesandbox.io/s/late-snowflake-9el46

Answer (score 2):

this is a simpl two select. Where frist select depend on second

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from "react"

const App = () => {

  const [state,setState] = useState({
    option1:["one","two"],
    option2: []
  })

  useEffect(()=> {
    (async () => {
      var a = await FETCH_API();
      console.log("sssss");
      setState({
        ...state,
        option2: a
      });
      console.log(a);
    })();
  },[state.option1])

  return(
    <div>
      <select>
        {
          state.option1.map((i,idx)=>{
            return(
              <option key={idx} value={i}>
              {i}
              </option>
            )
          })
        }

      </select>
      <select>
        {
          state.option2.map((i,idx)=>{
            return(
              <option key={idx} value={i}>
              {i}
              </option>
            )
          })
        }

      </select>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Not usefull solution

Comment: this is just an example might not work in sandbox because your api fetch server will not rechable throw internet